# connecting to mysql XE database

Tags: java, oracle

iam trying to connect to mysql database but this error occurs `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:test`
im using jdbc8 with oracle XE 18C with jdk 15 , and when i try to use
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); it gives me ClassNotFoundException
heres my code

```
package mypackage;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306:test";
        String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String username = "root";
        String password = "password";
        
        
        try
        {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL , username , password);

        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Oracle is **not** mysql, you cannot use a mysql driver to connect to oracle. You need an oracle driver.

Answer (score 1):

> im using jdbc8 with oracle XE 18C

You are using the wrong driver.

Although Oracle Corporation owns both the Oracle and MySQL database, they are separate databases and their drivers are not interchangeable.

If you are trying to access an Oracle database then you need an Oracle database driver and not a MySQL database driver.